# How to rename an AWS customer IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created a custom IAM policy, now I'm trying to rename it but I cannot find an option for it. The policy was not attached to anything yet. Is it possible to rename it or should I create a new policy with the correct name and delete the old one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now do it using the AWS command line tool with the [update-policy](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/organizations/update-policy.html)

```
aws organizations update-policy \
    --policy-id p-examplepolicyid111 \
    --name Renamed-Policy \
    --description "This description replaces the original."
```

Comment: Finding to policy id wasn't obvious to me. So I used [get_policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-policy.html) first: `aws iam get-policy --policy-arn <my-policy-arn>`

Comment: This is about updating `organizations` policies, which are a completely different thing.
The poster asked about `iam` policies

Comment: @Jan I got policy id from your answer, it's something like this `ANPAQ3EGRN6CFMC3CVPDI`, but the command`aws organizations update-policy` requires a policy id that must start with `p-`, so I think the answer provided here is contradictory and misleading.

Answer (score 40):

No, you cannot rename your custom policy. Only alternative:

- Copy policy
- Create a new policy with the new name and paste the policy
- Delete the old policy

[image]

Comment: i wish we had a 'mark as deprecated' button on SO! this one, as shown in @cyrille's answer, is no longer valid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67499413/4386191

Comment: @ZevAverbach I tried, it's still valid in 2024. Cyrille's answer is not about `aws iam`, it's about `aws organizations`